# How to improve insert performance in cassandra?

Tags: performance, cassandra, insert

I have a cassandra table with data in it. the schema is following.

When I make an insert to this table it takes 2 seconds which is really slow because we need to insert 1000 of records in real time. what am i missing? 
the list column will always have 100 values.

Please help.

```
CREATE TABLE dynodemo.normalized_sensor_data (
    user_id timeuuid,
    patient_sensor_session_id timeuuid,
    co2 int,
    dbp list<int>,
    ecg list<double>,
    ext_co int,
    ext_density int,
    ext_nitrousoxide int,
    ext_o3 int,
    ext_orgcmp int,
    ext_sulphuroxide int,
    ext_temp int,
    heart_rate list<int>,
    humidity list<double>,
    o2 int,
    pressure list<int>,
    pulse_ox_ir list<int>,
    pulse_ox_red list<int>,
    raw_ecg list<int>,
    respiration_rate list<int>,
    rr_int list<int>,
    sbp list<int>,
    session_end_time timestamp,
    session_start_time timestamp,
    spo2 list<double>,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, patient_sensor_session_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (patient_sensor_session_id ASC);
```

Comment: You need to give more information like write consistency, cluster size, driver etc

Comment: thanks for looking, the consistency is 1, cluster size is 2 nodes and driver is spark-cassendra connector Version: 1.5.0-M1. this setup is in AWS.

Comment: Lets isolate the problem first. Try inserting directly from CQL (without using a driver or connector) and note the time taken.

Comment: Are you reusing the session? Or are you trying to create cluster object for every transaction? Add some piece of code like how you are getting cluster instance, session and execution query? The information that you have provided is not sufficient to answer your question. But practically cassandra wont take that much time to inset. You are doing some thing mysterious which you have not described in your question,

Comment: Jeff Jirsa answer is also a valid point. Add a sample insert statement too in your question..

Comment: If you're on EC2 micro, it may not be suitable. Micro's CPU isn't adequate for Serious Cassandra as well as an attached EBS (Elastic Block Store) that can throttle Cassandra's performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below solved our issue even after using list in the column.

we are hosting spark worker node on the same server with cassandra node therefore localizing them helped in insertion.

one interesting thing is for us performance was same when we changed the lost column to text/string.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

Collections are considerably slower than normal cells. You're using a LOT of lists, assume those have a significant performance impact. You may find it's easier to serialize your 100 elements into json and store it as a text field (or even a compressed text field).

You're calling this a single insert, you have 12 lists of 100 items - it's actually 1200 cells being written, which is a fair number. A 2 second write is still unusual - it's probably due to some kind of pause (perhaps a GC pause due to the number of java objects you're creating with all of those lists)